# Sharedpreferences in button

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save in the sharedpreferences the background change and button state, in this case it would be like a new unlocked level where the user needs a score to unlock the level, but when leaving the app he returns to normal, how could I do to save this change?
Help me please, I've searched in several places for the answer but I was unsuccessful, I would be very grateful if you can help me!

[image]

```
ImageView imagem;
Button button,buttonScore;
TextView mScore;
private boolean newLevel = false;
private int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagem = findViewById(R.id.nivel);
    button = findViewById(R.id.botao);
    buttonScore = findViewById(R.id.bonusescore);
    mScore = findViewById(R.id.score);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("USER",MODE_PRIVATE);

    mScore.setText("" + score);

    buttonScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            score += 20;
            mScore.setText("" + score);
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!newLevel){
                if (score > 19){
                    score += -20;
                    mScore.setText("" + score);
                    imagem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
                    button.setText("UNLOCKED");
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    newLevel=true;
                }

            }else {
                imagem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vermelho));
                button.setText("LOCKED");
                button.setEnabled(true);
                newLevel=false;

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the below code:**

```
 final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("USER",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_user = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor_user.putBoolean("button_clicked", button.isSelected());
    editor_user.putBoolean("buttonScore_clicked", buttonScore.isSelected());
    editor_user.apply();

    Boolean boolean = editor_user.getBoolean("button_clicked",false);

    if(boolean == true)
    {
     imagem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul));
    }
    else
    {
    imagem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vermelho));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply my friend! But I was not successful

Comment: I can only save the score value, but the button state and background change are not saved, I tried it anyway ...
But thanks in advance for your help my dear friend!

Comment: Yes, but I'm still a little confused, an error appears in your code in the part: Boolean boolean = editor_user.getBoolean ("button_clicked", "");

Comment: what is the error? mentiom please. I havent compiled the code on my end so

Comment: Boolean boolean = editor_user.getBoolean ("button_clicked", "");

In getBoolean:
"Cannot solve method"

Comment: pls check the updates ans! remove "" and add false in the code

Comment: Unfortunately still unsuccessful my dear friend, I can not understand how saving the score was so simple, but now to save the state and change the background is so hard

Comment: did u got any crash in my code? what issue r u facing now?

Comment: Friend, thank you so much for your help! I was able to solve the problem after spending hours trying new methods

Comment: Most welcome! If the ans was useful to you then pls do accept the answer so that others may know the solution for the problem!

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to save score or btn state.

SharedPreferences provides interface for both reading and saving this data.

In order to read value :

```
sharedPreferences.getString(key1, default_value);
sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key2, default_value);
```

In order to save value :

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key1, value).apply();
sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key2, value).apply();
```

Official docs : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences